# Sending data from react component to css file

Tags: css, reactjs

In the CSS code for the `::before` pseudo-element, I want to dynamically change the box shadow color based on the color chosen in a React component.

React part

```
 <>
      <div className="card">
        <div className="percent">
          <div
            className="dot"
            style={{
              transform: `rotate(${3.6 * off}deg)`,
            }}
          ></div>
          <svg>
            <circle cx={70} cy={70} r={70}></circle>
            <circle
              cx={70}
              cy={70}
              r={70}
              style={{
                stroke: colors,
                strokeDasharray: 440,
                strokeDashoffset: 440 - (440 * off) / 100,
              }}
            ></circle>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
```

css part

```
.dot {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
  animation: anmationdot 2s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes anmationdot {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(calc(3.6 * 85));
  }
}
.dot::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: aqua;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px aqua, 0 0 30px aqua;
}
```

I encountered an error when attempting to use style and send it as the root element from React.

Comment: You should create a component , import your css in the component, apply the styling to elements you want, modify and extend styling based on component props. 
You can't pass JS to css file. Check "CSS Stylesheet", "CSS Modules" headings at : https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp

Comment: Are you asking how to dynamically determine a value (like color) in React, and have your CSS use that value? If so, declare a CSS variable in your component and pass it via the `style` attribute. Have your CSS class expect a variable of the same name.

Comment: @MohsenRobatjazi this way is good but i do not think it will work in this situation i cause the property i want to change is on seduclass not a normal elment

Comment: What is your `off` variable?

Comment: @Derek off is the percent that i have I use it with `strokeDashoffsetto `to set the value